# Program requires user to enter non duplicate numbers c++

Tags: c++, function

I have written a function in a program for entering a unique number but its not working. Something is wrong with the for loop.

I need to validate that employee id is unique.
I have made a structure named employee and "emp.id" is employee id. When the user inputs an id, it should not match previous Id's which user might have entered before. This is just a function of the main program, which validates that employee id is unique.

```
void uniquieid()    
{
    int check,i;
    string code;
    string tempemp1;
    cout<< "enter id";
    cin>> code;
    while(!(num-1))
    {
        for(i=0;i<=num-1;i++)
        {
            if(emp[i].id.compare(code)==0)//comparing 
            {
                check =1;
                cout<<"enter id again";
                break;
            }
            if(check=0)  //csaasc
            {
                emp[i].id=code;
            }
        }
    }
    getch();
}
```

Comment: Use `map<int, bool>` to check if user enters an already entered id. Looks like the `id` is string in your case. Use `map<string, bool>`

Comment: You must not update this question from my answer. If you want more help you can create a new question, and you can even use my answer there. You should give a more exact description of the symptoms.

Answer (score 2):

If the order that the ids are entered doesn't matter, I would do something like (note: untested):

```
using EmpIds = std::set<std::string>;

void addUniqueId(EmpIds& ids)
{
    std::pair<EmpIds::iterator, bool> inserted;
    const char* again = "";
    do {
        std::cout << "enter id" << again;
        again = " again";

        std::string id;
        if (!(std::cin >> id))
            throw std::runtime_error("No more ids!");
        inserted = ids.insert(id);
    } while (!inserted.second);
}
```

Comment: If I were you, I'd use [`std::unordered_set`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_set/unordered_set/) when you don't want data to be sorted, because it may be faster than [`std::set`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/)

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the employee structure?
Because from this, everything looks OK, but your `if` function refers to `emp`.
So something in your structure is causing the problem.
Without your structure, anyone answering probably won't be able to find the problem.

Right now, all i can advise you to do is store employee ids in a vector and iterate through it using a `for` loop.

You could do

```
void uniqueid() {
    std::vector<std::string> empIds;
    std::string code;
    CODE TO STORE IDs INTO VECTOR HERE;
    int vectorLength = empIds.size();
    std::cout << "enter id";
    std::cin >> code;
    for (int i = 0; i < vectorLength; i++) {
        if (empIds[i] == code) {
            std::cout << "enter id again";
            std::cin >> code;
        } else {
            empIds.push_back(code);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: storing in a `vector` and iterating will be less efficient than a map or hashtable.

Comment: I am new in c++ i dont know how to use vectors can you explian little more

Comment: basically a vector is an array with automatic memory management and (to me) it's easier to use. for more information [click here.](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/)

Answer (score 0):

For a start, something like the below should work.

```
map <string, bool> seen;

bool isUniqueId(string id)
{
    return seen[id];
}

void addId(string id)
{
    seen[id] = true;
}
```

From `main()`, whenever user inputs a string `id`, use `isUniqueId(id)` to ensure its unique, and if its unique, call `addId(id)`.

**Edit : (upon request from the OP)**

Your transformed code may look like below after using map.

```
// Global map, defaults to false
map <string, bool> seen;   // seen map to store if an id is seen already or not.
void uniqueId()    
{
    bool good = true; // set up a good flag to check if id is good or not.
    int numEmployees = 0; // Count to store number of employees with unique ids so far
    string id;

    cout<< "enter id\n";
    cin>> id;

    while(good)
    {
        good = false;   // Assume this is unique!
        if(seen[id])    // Check if we already saw this id before
        {
            good = true; // Alas! We already have seen this id
            cout<<"enter id again\n";
            continue; // If id already exists, ask for another id setting good = true;
            // Note that the above continue is NOT required as loop will run again (good = true).
            // Just for clarity sake.
        }
        else
        {
                // Voila, we have a new employee with unique id.
                seen[id] = true; // Unique, mark as seen now
                emp[numEmployees].id=code; // Note numEmployees here
                numEmployees++;  // Increment the count
        }
     }
    getch();
}
```

At the end of while loop, you would have successfully gotten a unique id from user, otherwise it will keep asking the user for new `id`.

Comment: I am new in c++ i dont know how to use map can you explian little more

Answer (score 0):

There are so many things wrong with the code, but maybe it should look more like this:

```
void uniqueid() {
    int check=1;
    string code;
    string tempemp1;
    cout<< "enter id";
    while(check) {
        cin >> code;
        check = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < num; ++i) {
            if (emp[i].id.compare(code)==0) {
                check = 1;
                cout << "enter id again";
                break;
            }
        }
        if (check==0) {
            /* emp[i].id=code; */
        }
    }
    getch();
}
```

Note how `int check=1;` starts at 1 to mean that the code needs re-entering.

So `while(check)` means that while the code is not unique keep going.

The for loop does the compare as before, but note the idiomatic form.

The other `if (check==0)` is outside the for loop and this means that no duplicates were detected so `code` can be used. However, I'm not sure which employee the `code` should apply to so I've just commented out the code.

Comment: Its working!! Great thanks!! but it has little problem I have to press enter twice to get to next line can you give me any suggestions

Comment: Add "\n" to both `cout` statements. Like this. `cout << "enter id\n";` and `cout << "enter id again";` You can see my answer for using map if you want to try it out.

Comment: I left in the 'getch()' which might mean pressing enter twice

Comment: Removing getch() solved the problem but its assigning last id to all employees (example: if i assign id 1 to first employee and id 2 to secong employee then while printing it is assigning ids for both employees as 2) can you give me any suggestions

Comment: I think it's time you asked another question showing updated code.