# I need to validate that employee id is unique

Tags: c++11

I have made a structure named employee and "emp.id" is employee id.

When the user inputs an id, it should not match previous Id's which user might have entered before.

This is just a function of the main program, which validates that employee id is unique.

code is working but when I am printing it is assigning last value of id to all of ids.

Please help.

```
void uniqueid()
{
  int check=1;
  string code;
  string tempemp1;

  cout<< "enter id";
  while(check) {
    cin >> code;
    check = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < num; ++i) {
      if (emp[i].id.compare(code)==0) {
        check = 1;
        cout << "enter id again";
        break;
      }
    }

    if (check==0) {
      emp[i].id=code; 
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please put some effort into your formatting. The extra blank lines are unnecessary and distracting. Also note the "code sample" button (looks like `{}`).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Program requires user to enter non duplicate numbers c++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26129214/program-requires-user-to-enter-non-duplicate-numbers-c)

Comment: This is not a duplicate question. I suggested the OP start a new question based on progress made on the previous one.

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be a non-trivial amount of code that's missing from your example; namely where `num`, and `emp` are defined, etc...

But, from a cursory examination, it appears that what's missing is `num` getting incremented, after successfully adding a new employee.

Also, maybe you haven't learned it yet, but in situations that involve uniqueness, `std::set` is going to be your friend; but in the kind of a situation that you've described, you'll probably end up using `std::map`.